# Can I initialize a template with variable type?

Tags: c++, c++11

(Using C++17)

I have a situation where I need to iterate through a list of subclasses:

```cpp
class S {}
class A : S {}
class B : S {}
class C : S {}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    shared_ptr<S> p;

    if (i == 0) {
        p = make_shared<A>();
    }
    else if (i == 1) {
        p = make_shared<B>();
    }
    else if (i == 2) {
        p = make_shared<C>();
    }

    // Do something with 'p'
}
```

This is quite ugly. I would much rather do something like this:

```cpp
class S {}
class A : S {}
class B : S {}
class C : S {}

for (S subclass_type : {A, B, C}) {
    shared_ptr<S> p = make_shared<subclass_type>();

    // Do something with 'p'
}
```

Is this possible in C++? Can you initialize a template class from a variable type? (Not just `shared_ptr`.)

Comment: "*Can you initialize a template class from a variable*" - not at runtime, no. Templates are only processed at compile-time, they simply don't exist at runtime.

Comment: Well, there are various approaches, which would be a variation on `template<typename ...Types> void dosomething{ /* ... */ }` and then invoking the template with explicitly specified variadic parameters. But in order to use them the shown code will have to be structured in a completely different way.

Comment: Could you please clarify if said list of classes is known at compile time in your use case?

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, the list of subclasses is known at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

You need to build something that is constant at compile time.
`std::array<std::shared_ptr<S>>` will be such a something.
Once you created that it is easy to loop over that at runtime.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

struct S
{
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

struct A : S
{
    void do_something() override { std::cout << "A"; };
};

struct B : S
{
    void do_something() override { std::cout << "B"; };
};

struct C : S
{
    void do_something() override { std::cout << "C"; };
};


// Function that will create an instance of each type passed
// create_all will return a fixed size array of shared_ptr's to S
template<typename... types_t>
auto create_all()
{
    // check all types passed in are derived from S
    static_assert((std::is_base_of_v<S, types_t>,...));
    
    // check the base class is not passed in (since it is abstract)
    static_assert((!std::is_same_v<S, types_t>, ...));
    
    // Create an array with shared_ptr instances of each type
    return std::array<std::shared_ptr<S>, sizeof...(types_t)>{ std::make_shared<types_t>()... };
}


int main()
{
    // You need something known at compile time,
    
    auto objects = create_all<A, B, C>();

    // Now just use a range based for loop to 
    // call all the objects one by one
    for (const auto& object : objects)
    {
        object->do_something();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do I understand this correctly that you have instantiated a list containing one of each subclass, and you iterate through this list?

Comment: Not a list but a `std::array<std::shared_ptr<S>,3>`. But yes it contains one instance of each subclass. Say you want two of each you can do `create_all<A,A,B,B,C,C>()`. An then yes I iterate over that array and call do_something on each of the shared_ptr's

Comment: The static_assert-s by the way use [fold-expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), and the array constructor expands make_shared for each `types_t`. You can see this happening here at cppinsights.io (line number 69) https://cppinsights.io/s/20a100a0 (hit the play button on the site to show the expanded code)

Answer (score 1):

For above example, manual list do the job. That is simple enough:

```
for (auto p : { std::make_shared<A>(), std::make_shared<B>(), std::make_shared<C>() }) {
    // Do something with 'p'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the smart pointer is somewhat irrelevant to the actual issue. Even if you would allocate the objects on the stack you'd face the same problem. You cannot use the runtime `i` as template argument, also not indirectly. However, you already have runtime polymorphism so no template voodoo is needed here.

You can write a Factory:

```
struct S_Factory {
    std::shared_ptr<S> make(size_t i) {
        switch(i) {
           case 0: return std::make_shared<A>();
           case 1: return std::make_shared<B>();
           case 2: return std::make_shared<C>();
        }
    }
    static constexpr size_t num_sub = 3;
};
```

Then

```
for (size_t i=0; i<S_Factory::num_sub; ++i) {
    auto p = S_Factory::make(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with your derived classes inheriting public from `S`, you could follow this approach:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class S {};
class A : public S {};
class B : public S {};
class C : public S {};

template <typename F, typename T, typename ...Args>
void iterateOverBaseS(const F& f, const T& t, const Args&... args) {
    f(t);

    if constexpr (sizeof... (args)) {
        iterateOverBaseS(f, args...);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<S>> objs{};

    iterateOverBaseS([&objs](const S& s) {
        objs.push_back(std::make_shared<S>(s));
        }, S(), A(), B(), C());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to C++20, you can make a helper function that executes whatever you want on each derived type

```
template<class F>
void for_each_S_class(F&& f) {
    f.template operator()<A>(); 
    f.template operator()<B>(); 
    f.template operator()<C>();
}
```

And then you can use this to iterate over the derived types, doing whatever you want.

```
    for_each_S_class([]<typename T>()->void{
        std::shared_ptr<S> p = std::make_shared<T>();
        p->foo();
    });
```

One advantage of this method is that it doesn't actually require you to create *instances* of the class to iterate over. This iterates over the classes directly. However, this can also be a downside, as the body of the method is not shared, so there is bytecode for each `p->foo`. But back on the upsides, since there *is* separate bytecode for each, the compiler can probably optimize this better, eliminating the indirection, and even inlining the method calls.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d6f76a06244d4bf